# How to overwrite document_base_url configuration of stfalcon/tinymce-bundle?

Tags: jquery, symfony, tinymce-4

Here is code

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    include_jquery: true
    tinymce_jquery: true
    selector: ".tinymce"
    language: %locale%
    theme:
        advanced:
            relative_urls: false
            remove_script_host: false
            convert_urls: true
            document_base_url: 'http://yourdomain.com'
            plugins:
                - "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
                - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                - "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | stfalcon | example"
            image_advtab: true
```

I have sub domain system and I want to overwrite document_base_url: 'http://yourdomain.com' where 'http://yourdomain.com' will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

```
{{ tinymce_init({
    theme: {
        'mailtemplate':
        {
            'document_base_url': baseUrlName
        }
    }
})}}
```

Where baseUrlName will come from controller